# VB.net ASP.net class Library Project Shared (Static) variable inside public class

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

We have a class library project is use to hold our basic data definitions, sql functions and generic functions. This class library is used in or winform project and our asp.net project.

In one of the classes we have our generic functions setup and shared variables.

```
Public Class Generic
    Public Shared CurrentDeviceUniqueIdentifier As String
    Public Shared TimeDiffFromServer As Long
    Public Shared myLogger As Logger

....
end Class
```

And they are accessed in class library also in the winform/asp.net project.

```
 If Generic.myLogger IsNot Nothing Then Generic.myLogger.WriteLog(...)
```

These shared variables aren't causing any problems winform project since there is single instance of these variables and system doesn't have any issues.

But the asp.net project gets these shared variables confused across sessions hense they are shared.

I could convert the class to a module since system is designed in VB instead of C#. But not sure if that would resolve the issue.(it should)
In case in the future we might want to convert to C# and this wouldn't work.

But I was curious is there any other way to get around this problem where shared variables to lock down into asp.net session.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have a shared method or property that is used by different user sessions in an ASP.Net app. So what's your problem?

Comment: Static (Shared) values *by themselves* don't cause any problems at all.  But you may be *using* them in a problematic way, particularly in a multi-threaded multi-user environment.  What exactly *is* the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: [How to choose between....](http://www.articlesbase.com/programming-articles/how-to-choose-from-viewstate-session-application-cache-and-cookies-443393.html)

Comment: Loggers per client goes to different folder, so when there is multiple clients logs gets mixed up. 
Cannot convert it to session coding since this class library is used inside the class library also, which this class library is used inside winforms also would cause problems.

Comment: I guess I need to ask is there an alternative to shared, like using module but not prefered method.

Answer (score 0):

Static classes and data are shared across ASP.NET sessions.  Period.  Changing to `Module` would not change the problem since _everything" in a `Module` is shared.  If you want to have separate instances for each session then you'll have to make them "not `Shared`" and change your code to store instances in session:

```
Session("Logger") = new Logger()
```

There's no "hack" that I'm aware of to allow separate Shared classes by session in ASP.NET.

Comment: Cannot convert it to session coding since this class library is used inside the class library also, which this class library is used inside winforms also would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

VB Shared variable or C# static variable are AppDomain wide (for practical purpose, you can think of that as process wide) and therefore you have a single value.

To have a different value for different ASP.Net session, you have to put it in the Session dictionary, there is no way around that.

You might also want to look at threading issues. In general, ASP.Net processes request concurrently, and if you have shared variables (even in the same session), that might be accessed concurrently and your code need to be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

For now I needed a simple and fast solution inside the class library. Converted the class to module. Removed all shared (static) Codes from all variables and functions. As of now it all works as in functionality and compiling. I am hoping the data crossing over should be resolved too. I will keep an eye on the logs to see if it happens again but I doubt it will.

I still prefer another way of doing this where it works in winforms and asp.net so we can convert to C# in the future.

For reference changed version of the code:

```
Public Module Generic
    Public CurrentDeviceUniqueIdentifier As String
    Public TimeDiffFromServer As Long
    Public myLogger As Logger

....
end Class
```

Comment: Well, could you not simply kept the older class, and removed the shared keywords from that class? I assume that your code must have created a instance of that class when required - so removing shared keywords from those public vars of that class should still work. I of course as noted assume your existing code creates an instance of the class, or this much suggests you using the shared to create global vars to the project.

Comment: just removing shared doesn't work because object like logger is called in one time initial page but not sent down to functions or other classes. Shared is used for global variable definition yes. But IIS makes it too much of a global across sessions which causing the problem. Only other way is i can think of is add the same parameters to each class and assign that but that would make a ton of code change. seems like module is the only way to go right now. Wish there was another way.

Comment: Well this didnt work, MODULE is same as shared(static) across app _domain, which gets shared. I have to modify each class to get object to store the commonly shared items like the logger. 
    class blah 
    dim myLogger as Logger 
and assign it on class calls and assign it sigh this is gonna take some time. So annoying there isnt a way to do this.